# Django error redirecting

Tags: python, django, django-models

Cannot assign "HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/carts/"": "Order.cart" must be a "Carts" instance". what does this error mean in django? New to django please help

```
def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id")
    if cart_id == None:
        return redirect("cart")
    cart = Carts.objects.get(id = cart_id)
    return cart


def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    get_data = super(CheckoutView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    cart = self.get_object()
    user_checkout_id = request.session.get("user_checkout_id")
    if user_checkout_id != None:
        user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.get(id = user_checkout_id)
        billing_address_id = request.session.get("billing_address_id")
        shipping_address_id =  request.session.get("shipping_address_id")
        if billing_address_id == None or shipping_address_id == None:
            return redirect("order_address")
        else:
            billing_address = UserAddress.objects.get(id=billing_address_id)
            shipping_address = UserAddress.objects.get(id=shipping_address_id)
        try:
            new_order_id = request.session["order_id"]
            new_order = Order.objects.get(id=new_order_id)
        except:
            new_order = Order()
            request.session["order_id"] = new_order.id
        new_order = Order()
        new_order.cart = cart
        new_order.user = user_checkout
        new_order.billing_address = billing_address
        new_order.shipping_address = shipping_address
        new_order.save()

    return redirect("checkout")
```

class Order(models.Model):

```
cart = models.ForeignKey(Carts)
user =  models.ForeignKey(UserCheckout, null=True)
shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress, related_name='shipping_address', null=True)
billing_address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress, related_name='billing_address', null=True)
shipping_total_price = models.DecimalField(default=5.99, decimal_places=2, max_digits=50)
order_total = models.DecimalField( decimal_places=2, max_digits=50)


def __str__(self):
    return self.carts.id
```

class Carts(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
items =  models.ManyToManyField(Variation, through=CartItem)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
tax_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, default=0.085)
subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=250.00)
tax_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=250.00)
total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=250.00)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

Comment: You need to show your actual code.

Comment: I think you need to show the `get_object` method. Also note you really shouldn't be making changes in a get request, only on post.

Comment: Done...However I just wanna know what this error actually means cant find it in documentation

Comment: It means what it says: you are trying to assign a redirect to the "cart" attribute of an Order. And that's because you return a redirect from `get_object` if the cart_id is none.